# Python packages -- system and user's have different versions

Tags: python, pip, easy-install

if I have `sudo pip install`  a python package to a system-wide location

and I `pip install --user` a different python package to my user location

What would python use when I do `import packagename`? How do I control the version? or python always uses the most updated one?

Comment: You might want to look into Python Virtual Environments (http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) as venvs allow you to manage package versions quite well.

Comment: Did you install the same package in system-wide location and in user location?